# Local HTML file looks different when uploaded

Tags: html, web

I am developing a website using Adobe Dreamweaver, and when I open up the HTML file in chrome from my local computer, everything is as it should be (mainly the margins). But when I upload it to my hosting service all the margins go wrong. I have compared the source code and they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to upload the CSS files as well. You can see them in your code by looking for `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">` tags.

You could open the Chrome dev-tools window by pressing `F12` and going to the `Console` tab where you would probably see some `Failed to load resource` messages indicating that it couldn't find the files.

Just upload them and make sure they're in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Because your paths for resources may be referenced as absolute paths(for example: `<img src="c:\mydocs\myimage.jpg">`). Check all your paths and tehn come back if they dont fix your issues